# ArcGIS for Javascript : Locate Widget Activate Popup for Layers X > Z?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, address-parsing

Using ArcGIS for Javascript I have a map with a **City Council District** feature layer. I would like for the user to enter their address in the 'Address Finder' / Locate Widget (that's what it's called in Flex) and when the dot appears on the map I want the City Council District Layer popups to be triggered.

The popup currently says, **"You are in [Councilor]'s district, number [Distr#]."**

So if they type in their address, **"1234 Sesame Street"** and that is in **district #3** which is Councilor Smith, what I want to happen is to see the address finder drop the dot on the map where the address is and have a popup say, **"You are in Smith's district, number 3."**

Is this possible and if so, how?

Update: 08APR14

I am including my working code as I progress. When I get this working I will post it as an answer.

The following code will drop a pop-up window that is empty onto the screen. Now I am trying to figure out how to programmatically "click" on the screen at the center of the GeoCoder's search results.

```
require
    (
        [
            "esri/map",
            "esri/dijit/Popup",
            "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
            "dojo/dom-class",
            "dojo/dom-construct",
            "dojo/on",
            "dojox/charting/themes/Dollar",
            "esri/dijit/Geocoder",
            "esri/geometry/Extent",
            "esri/SpatialReference",
            "dojo/domReady!"
        ],
        function( Map, Popup, FeatureLayer, domClass, domConstruct, on, theme, Geocoder, Extent, SpatialReference )
        {
            var popup = Popup( { titleInBody: false }, domConstruct.create("div") );

            var locatorURL = "http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer";

            var map = new Map("map", { basemap: "gray", center: [-95.989658, 36.155520], zoom: 13, infoWindow: popup });

            domClass.add( map.infoWindow.domNode, "myTheme" );

            var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer
            (
                "http://maps.cityoftulsa.org/gis/rest/services/StarterMaps/extCouncilDistricts/MapServer/0",
                { mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND, opacity: 0.4, outFields: ["*"]  }
            );

            map.addLayer(featureLayer);

            // XMin: -10779302.92 YMin: 4210801.07 XMax: -10504129.62 YMax: 4394249.94
            // Taken from: http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=map_currentextent
            var extCityOfTulsa = new Extent
            (
                -10779302.92,
                4210801.07,
                -10504129.62,
                4394249.94,
                new SpatialReference
                (
                    { wkid:3857 }
                )
            );

            var myGeocoder = [ { url: locatorURL, name: "Address Locator", singleLineFieldName: "Single Line Input", searchExtent: extCityOfTulsa } ];

            var geocoder = new Geocoder
            (
                {
                    map: map,
                    geocoderMenu: true,
                    value: "175 East 2nd Street",
                    maxLocations: 10,
                    autoNavigate: false,
                    autoComplete: true,
                    arcgisGeocoder: true,
                    geocoder: myGeocoder
                },
                "search"
            );

            geocoder.startup();

            function popThatCouncil(results)
            {
                var resGeom, resFeat;

                for (var i = 0; i < results.results.results.length; i++)
                {
                    console.debug(results.results.results[i], " at index ", i);
                    resGeom = results.results.results[0].feature.geometry;
                    resFeat = results.results.results[0].feature;
                }

                map.centerAndZoom(resGeom, 20);
                map.infoWindow.setFeatures(resFeat);
                map.infoWindow.show(resGeom);
                geocoder.inputNode.blur();
            }

            geocoder.on( "find-results", popThatCouncil );
        }
    );
```