# Getting popup with layer attributes to display after using address search/geocoder widget?

Tags: web-mapping, arcgis-online, arcgis-web-appbuilder

Using Web AppBuilder and ArcGIS Online, I want to let my user(s) enter an address on the "Geocoder Widget" and have an automatic popup that displays. I know how to configure the content of the popup. I know I can change the Geocoder to search for specific features/attributes.

Example: I have three school boundaries (High School districts, Middle School Districts, and Elementary School Districts) that overlap each other. I want to create an app that lets someone Enter their address and it spits out their neighborhood HS, MS, and ES (I will be adding driving directions and descriptions of the schools in the pop up).

[ArcGIS for Javascript : Locate Widget Activate Popup for Layers X > Z?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92016) asks the same thing I believe but was never answered or commented on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to go with using the Information Lookup template for ArcGIS online. It does not give me the flexibility I want, but it does the job I need it to do. I hope this is helpful for others.

I created a webmap with all of my layers and symbolized them as I wanted. I configured the popups to look the way I wanted (images, links, directions). I started the Information Lookup App Template and simply uploaded my webmap.

Now, when I use the address locator a popup window opens displaying popups for all layers I told it to. When adding multiple layers for query put "|" in between.

There is a bug with information lookup template. When you designate lookup layers from your webmap, it breaks the URLs. No idea why, but I informed Esri Tech Support.

[image: Example of adding multiple layers for display in popup]

Comment: If Esri support issued you with a bug number it is always useful to include that.

Answer (score 0):

[MangoMap](https://mangomap.com) has the behaviour you require by default. Just to an address search and an info window popups up with information for any features that contain the location of the geosearch.

Disclaimer - I work for MangoMap

Comment: Interesting. I may end up going that route. Does the price on your website reflect "credits" are anything like how Esri works? We service 40,000 students and there would be a lot of visitors to the webmap

Comment: No there is no credit system, it's just a flat rate. Mango can easily handle that level of traffic. You can also email me directly (chris@mangomap.com).